# Can an ISP be fined for Copyright Infringement on their networks?

Tags: copyright, internet

I was told from a local ISP that they are shutting off accounts for copyright infringement, because they personally can be fined if they do not.

Has there been any news worthy events regarding ISPs and copyright infrigement that I should be aware of?

Can anyone comment on the validity of this statement? Sources preferably.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the USA the action is valid and required for the ISP to protect itself from copyright infringement. See http://www.austlii.edu.au/au/journals/MurUEJL/2002/51.html

> Moreover, the DMCA relieves ISPs from direct liability for their passive transmission, reception, or temporary storage of material in their networks provided the they adopt policies for terminating subscribers who are repeat offenders and implement industry-developed technical measures used by content providers to protect their work

Answer (score 2):

See this article http://www.reuters.com/article/us-cox-copyright-idUSKBN0U02OD20151217 which reports that Cox Communications was ordered to pay $25 million for copyright infringement. So apparently an ISP cannot only be sued for copyright infringment (anyone can be sued for anything), but can also lose the case.